# How to count all occurrences of a word in a string using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find the number of times 'bob' occurs in a string of characters like 'abdebobdfhbobob'.

My code (that I found through another stackoverflow question) is:

```
s = 'abdebobdfhbobob'  
print 'The number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(s.count('bob'))
```

This code prints out: **The number of times bob occurs is: 2** which is not correct for what I need as the answer should be 3.

The issue is that this code does not count 'abdebobdfh**bobob**' as two different bobs, which is what I want.

How can I fix the code to count the bobob part of the string as two separate bobs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), `str.count()` return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range `[start, end]`. You can use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regular expression in order to find the overlapped strings:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'abdebobdfhbobob'
>>> len(re.findall(r'(?=bob)', s))
3
```

If you don't want to use regex you can use a generator expression within the `sum()` function that will iterate over the all sub-strings with length 3 and count the number of those that are equal to 'bob':

```
>>> sum(s[i:i+3] == 'bob' for i in range(len(s)-2))
3
```

Comment: It is worth noticing that if the counter is intended to be **case insensitive**, ``s`` should be replaced by ``s.lower()`` in the solutions above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regular expressions you can create all triplets from the string using `zip` and then use `list.count`:

```
>>> word = 'bob'
>>> triplets = (''.join(k) for k in zip(*[s[i:] for i in range(len(word))]))
>>> triplets.count(word)
3
```

The triplets are created by zipping these strings:

```
     ▼     ▼ ▼
'abdebobdfhbobob'
'bdebobdfhbobob'
'debobdfhbobob'
     ▲     ▲ ▲
```

If you don't mind working with tuples:

```
>>> word = 'bob'
>>> triplets = zip(*[s[i:] for i in range(len(word))])
>>> triplets.count(tuple(word))
3
```

**Tip**: If you're going to count other words as well, use a `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

We can just check all possible candidates:

```
def count_substrings(sub, main):
    n = len(sub)
    return sum(sub == main[i : i+n] for i in range(len(main) - n + 1))

s = 'abdebobdfhbobob'
sub = 'bob'
print('The number of times %s occurs is: %d' % (sub, count_substrings(sub, s)))  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

why do not you make it easy?

```
bobc=0
for i in range (0,len(s)-2):
    if s[i:i+3]=='bob':
        bobc+=1
        i=+1
print('Number of bob:'+str(bobc))
```